# Bake parent animation but also keep child animation

Tags: animation, bones, baking, parent

I am trying to bake an animation, from a parent bone to a child bone. While baking the main animation from the parent bone, and also keeping the local animation of the child bones intact.

I have a center bone, that causes the child bones around it to spin in a circle (as if it was a wheel). The child bones themselves also make a 180 degree rotation. When i bake the animation through Object > Animation > Bake Action... the rotating "wheel" is baked. But the rotation of the childs is lost in the process.

I know it would be simpler to keep everything together. However, the project i need this for requires me to export all the childs as a seperate file with their own animation. But i do want them to retain the exact animation as i see in my viewport.

[image]

Hoping someone can help me out, i cannot seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have each bone in a separate object, you have to bake the Armature as an object, when you bake the action enable "Clear Parents" so you can export its animation separately

[image]

As you can see, the two bones that have already been baked no longer have the Relationship Line that is shown when they are related.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I thought i tried every combination of checkboxes but apparently not. You're a lifesaver!